# JavaScript submit button returns isTrusted true when programmatically triggered

Tags: javascript

I am experiencing with the [isTrusted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) event property. I stumbled upon an unexpected result so I was wondering why this is happening and if it is intended.

```
<form id="form1" @submit.prevent="submit">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<form id="form2">
  <button type="button" @click="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
document.querySelector('#form1 button').click(); // isTrusted = true
document.querySelector('#form2 button').click(); // isTrusted = false
```

As you can see, when clicking the first submit button programmatically `isTrusted` returns true which I find is unexpected. Is this intended?

Comment: You seem to be using some kind of library or framework (`@submit.prevent="submit"`, etc.). Which one? They often provide synthetic events, in which case all bets are off. Do you see the same results when you work purely at the DOM level?

Comment: Are you using Vue.js here?

Comment: I get `false` consistently doing this directly with the DOM with Chrome, Firefox, and Legacy Edge: https://codesandbox.io/s/so-question-61709680-2713j

Comment: Yes, I am using Vue.js. It seems like that's the reason. Thanks! Submit an answer and I'll accept it if You'd like.